# LaTeX rasterizes Mathematica 10 PDF figures when PDF document is printed, but not Mathematica 9 figures

Tags: printing, wolfram-mathematica

Not sure whether to post here or on Mathematica SE (or somewhere else), but I'll give it a go here first.

I recently updated to Mathematica 10 and then discovered that when I printed a LaTex generated PDF document that included PDF figures from both Mathematica 9 and 10, the PDF figures made in Mathematica 10 were rasterized when printing, while those from Mathematica 9 came out just as normal.

I'm using a Mac and TexShop, and this happens when printing either directly from TexShop or Preview, but not if I print from Adobe Acrobat Pro. The PDF figures do however print fine by themselves using Preview, suggesting that something happens along the way in LaTeX.

I'm mostly just curious as to why this happens. And as I would like others to print the document, I would like it to print the same result across different PDF viewers.

Does anyone know what causes the described behavior? And perhaps how to avoid it?

ADDED: Example LaTex file

```
\documentclass[prl,preprint]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.5 \textwidth]{./testFigureMathematica10.pdf}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How do you compile the tex document? How do you include the Mathematica figure?

Comment: I compile using Pdftex. (Just using the standard settings in TexShop).

Comment: Could you make your file `testFigureMathematica10.pdf` available online so that we van compile on our side? What happens if you compile with `pdflatex`?

Comment: Any good way to upload online without dropbox etc? When I run pdflatex from command line same thing happens. But not sure whether it really runs pdflatex, as this is what I see: '$pdflatex testMathematica.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/MacPorts 2012_5)'

Comment: That is also quite an old LaTeX installation. There are many free upload places on the web. Just upload to one of them and post the link

Comment: http://www.megafileupload.com/4G6h/testFigureMathematica9.pdf

Comment: http://www.megafileupload.com/4G6i/testFigureMathematica10.pdf

Comment: I've updated the LaTex installation, but the problem still persists: `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdflatex)`

Comment: I cannot open your files.

Comment: Not open or not download? I tried now and had to press slow "Slow download" twice before the download window opened. But then the files downloaded and could be saved and viewed correctly in a PDF viewer.